# C program to compare two non equal size arrays

Tags: c, arrays, compare

i have write a program to compare 2 different size arrays,program should to compare the arrays and return a index of first array where the equal starting,but for some syntax or logical problem the program not working.So please see the code and tell me where is the problem.Thanks in advanse.

```
  #include "stdafx.h"
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <math.h>

   int subArray( int first[], int size1, int second[], int size2)
  {

 int key = second [0] ; //init key of first element in second array
 int i;
 int y;
 int found,count;


 for (i = 0 ;size1 < i; i++) 
{
    if (first[i] == key)
  count ++;   
  found = 1;
}

     if (found== 1)  // should compare first and second array and return -1 if not equal
  {
   for (y = 0 ;size2 < y; y++) 
    {
      if (first[i] != second[y])

        result =-1;
    else
    {
        i++;

    }

  }


  return result=count; //return index of first array where equal startring
}


int main()

{

  int result;
  int sizeArr1;
  int sizeArr2;
  int  arr1[40]={0};
  int  arr2[40]={0}; 
 // taking input and storing it in first array
   scanf_s("%d", &sizeArr1);
   for(int i = 0; i < sizeArr1; ++i)
   {
    scanf_s("%d", &arr1[i]);

   }
     // taking input and storing it in second array
     scanf_s("%d", &sizeArr2);
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
   {
    scanf_s("%d", &arr2[i]);

    }
     result = subArray(arr1,sizeArr1,arr2,sizeArr2);
     printf("%d",result);
   }
```

Comment: "Not working" is never a good problem description. What happens? Does it crash? Does it print nothing? Does it sometimes get the right answer? etc. Give the input, expected output and actual output. Also what have you done to debug it - such as running in a debugger and/or adding more debug prints?

Comment: @Alexander Bazikalo Do you want to determine whether the second array is a sub-array of the first array?

Comment: Learn to indent correctly your code. Good indentation can help to find subtle typos such as the one pointed out by the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you forgot about block:

```
for (i = 0; size1 < i; i++) 
{
    if (first[i] == key)
    {
        count++;   
        found = 1;
    }
}
```

In your original code `found` will be set to `1` in every `for` loop iteration without dependency on `if` condition.

NOTE: your code formatting is really bad, code indentation and blank (empty) lines are totally random. That's all.

Comment: If this is the code as written, there might also be an issue with the conditional on line 24 (`if (first[i] != second[y])`) as it doesn't appear to have any associated code.

Comment: Nope ;) there are lines below, after single blank line - this blank line is ignored by compiler, but - I agree - such things makes the code near totally unreadable.

Comment: So please kindly help to modify this code if you can.

Comment: @VillageTech Ah, didn't realise such blank lines were ignored (I've never given myself the pleasure of writing code creative enough to use such features).

Comment: @AlexanderBazikalo - sorry, try to do it yourself, but before your try, read something about good practices in code formatting. Believe me, you must can do it. If I do it for you, you still will don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Your `int subArray()` function's closing bracket was missing and your `result` variable should be global.
Other errors i have mentioned in the code.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

int result;

   int subArray( int first[], int size1, int second[], int size2)
  {

 int key = second [0] ; //init key of first element in second array
 int i;
 int y;
 int found,count=0;


 for (i = 0 ;size1 > i; i++)   // comparator sign was opposite
{
    if (first[i] == key){      // brackets were missing here.
      count = i;   
      found = 1;
      printf("value found in array 1 at index number : ");
    }
}

 if (found== 1)  // should compare first and second array and return -1 if not equal
 {


for (y = 0 ;size2 > y; y++)   // comparator sign was opposite
{
  if (first[i] != second[y])

    result =-1;
else
{
    i++;

}



}
  }


  return result=count; //return index of first array where equal startring
}


int main()

{


  int sizeArr1;
  int sizeArr2;
  int  arr1[40]={0};
  int  arr2[40]={0}; 
 // taking input and storing it in first array
   scanf("%d", &sizeArr1);
   for(int i = 0; i < sizeArr1; ++i)
   {
    scanf("%d", &arr1[i]);

   }
     // taking input and storing it in second array
     scanf("%d", &sizeArr2);
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeArr2; ++i)    // here instead of taking array2 size it was hard coded to 5
   {
    scanf("%d", &arr2[i]);
}
 result = subArray(arr1,sizeArr1,arr2,sizeArr2);
 printf("%d",result);
}
```

Comment: not working , could you check,i thing some logical error, the program doesn't compare and return anything...

Comment: give input and expected output.

Comment: @AlexanderBazikalo answer edited with corrected code and comments.

Answer (score 0):

For starters the function declaration is illiterate.

The parameters that denote arrays shall be declared with the qualifier const because the arrays are not being changed in the function.

Secondly the number of elements in arrays shall have the type `size_t`. So the return type of the function also shall have the type `size_t`.

If the second array is not a sub-array of the first array then the function should return the size of the first array that is the index that is beyond of the range of valid indices for the array.

Your function 1) logically is invalid because it only once finds the position of the first character of the second array though the sub-array can start from some other position and 2) it has bugs as for example this loop

```
 for (i = 0 ;size1 < i; i++) 
{
    if (first[i] == key)
  count ++;   
  found = 1;
}
```

neither iteration of which will be executed because size1 can not be less than 0 provided that size1 is not a negative number.

The function can be declared and defined the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

size_t subArray( const int first[], size_t size1, const int second[], size_t size2 )
{
    size_t pos = size1;

    if ( !( size1 < size2 ) )
    {
        for ( size_t i = 0; pos == size1 && i < size1 - size2 + 1; i++ )
        {
            size_t j = 0;

            while ( j < size2 && first[i+j] == second[j] ) j++;

            if ( j == size2 ) pos = i;
        }
    }

    return pos;
}

int main(void) 
{
    int first[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
    int second[] = { 3, 4, 5 };
    const size_t SIZE1 = sizeof( first ) / sizeof( *first );
    const size_t SIZE2 = sizeof( second ) / sizeof( *second );

    size_t pos = subArray( first, SIZE1, second, SIZE2 );

    if ( pos != SIZE1 )
    {
        for ( size_t i = 0; i < SIZE2; i++ )
        {
            printf( "%d ", first[pos + i] );
        }

        putchar( '\n' );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
3 4 5
```